# A box pop up that asks the user to please wait while the program loops through and converts all the relevant files

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, jlabel

I am writing a small program that converts files, and I wanted to have a box pop up that asks the user to please wait while the program loops through and converts all the relevant files, but I am running into a small problem. The box that pops up should have a JLabel and a JButton, while the user is "waiting" I wanted to display a message that says please wait, and a disabled "OK" JButton, and then when its finished I wanted to set the text of the JLabel to let them know that It successfully converted their files, and give them a count of how many files were converted. (I wrote a method called alert that sets the text of the label and enables the button.) The problem is That while the program is running, the box is empty, the Label and the Button are not visible, when it finishes, label appears with the final text that I want and the button appears enabled. I am not sure exactly what is going on, I tried changing the modifiers of the JLabel and JButton several times but I cant seem to get it to work correctly. Here is the code for the box that pops up, any help is greatly appricated.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class PleaseWait extends javax.swing.JFrame{

    private static final int height = 125;
    private static final int width = 350;
    final static JLabel converting = new JLabel("Please Wait while I convert your files");
    private static JButton OK = new JButton("OK");



    public PleaseWait(){
        // creates the main window //
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
        mainWindow.setTitle("Chill For A Sec");
        mainWindow.setSize(width, height);
        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        // creates the layouts//
        JPanel mainLayout = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel textLayout = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel buttonLayout = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        // Sets Text //
        converting.setText("Please wait while I convert your files");

        // disables button //
        OK.setEnabled(false);

        // adds to the layouts //
        textLayout.add(converting);
        buttonLayout.add(OK);
        mainLayout.add(textLayout, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainLayout.add(buttonLayout, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // adds to the frame //
        mainWindow.add(mainLayout);

        // sets everything visible //
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void alert(){
        OK.setEnabled(true);
        String total = String.valueOf(Convert.result());
        converting.setText("Sucsess! " + total + " files Converted");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show were you call `alert()`?

Answer (score 1):

Okay here's the issue. You are extending the JFrame . That means your class IS a JFrame.

When you create the `PleaseWait` frame you don't do anything to it. This is the empty box you are seeing. You are instead creating a *different* JFrame in your constructor. Remove your `mainWindow` and instead just use `this`. Now all of your components will be added to your `PleaseWait` object. That should fix your blank box issue.

Comment: I gave it a shot, but it didn't fix the problem. However, Thank you for letting me know about that, that is useful information. Also, alert is called in my convert function, The inital call works like this:

PleaseWait holdOnaSec = new PleaseWait();
the important stuff in the convert method 
holdOnaSec.alert();

Answer (score 1):

You need an application to create your frame first. This is a simple example of such application.

```
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.*;

public class Application {
  boolean packFrame = false;

  //Construct the application
  public Application() {
    PleaseWait frame = new PleaseWait();
    //Validate frames that have preset sizes
    //Pack frames that have useful preferred size info, e.g. from their layout
    if (packFrame) {
      frame.pack();
    }
    else {
      frame.validate();
    }
    //Center the window
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Dimension frameSize = frame.getSize();
    if (frameSize.height > screenSize.height) {
      frameSize.height = screenSize.height;
    }
    if (frameSize.width > screenSize.width) {
      frameSize.width = screenSize.width;
    }
    frame.setLocation((screenSize.width - frameSize.width) / 2, (screenSize.height - frameSize.height) / 2);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.convert();

  }

  //Main method
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new Application();
  }
}
```

You have to slightly modify your frame to add controls to the content pane. You can do some work after frame is created, then call alert.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PleaseWait extends JFrame {

  private static final int height = 125;
  private static final int width = 350;
  final static JLabel converting = new JLabel();
  private static JButton OK = new JButton("OK");
  BorderLayout borderLayout1 = new BorderLayout();
  JPanel contentPane;
  int count;

  public PleaseWait(){
    contentPane = (JPanel)this.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(borderLayout1);
    this.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    this.setTitle("Chill For A Sec");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    // creates the layouts//
    JPanel mainLayout = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel textLayout = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel buttonLayout = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    // Sets Text //
    converting.setText("Please wait while I convert your files");

    // disables button //
    OK.setEnabled(false);
    OK.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });

    // adds to the layouts //
    textLayout.add(converting);
    buttonLayout.add(OK);
    mainLayout.add(textLayout, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainLayout.add(buttonLayout, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // adds to the frame //
    contentPane.add(mainLayout);
  }

  public void convert(){
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
      System.out.println("Copy "+i);
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      }
      count++;
    }
    alert();

  }
  public void alert(){
    OK.setEnabled(true);
//        String total = String.valueOf(Convert.result());
    converting.setText("Sucsess! " + count + " files Converted");
  }

}
```

Comment: I thought that _repaint_ will be useful after updating the controls but controls are smart enough to update themselves.

Comment: So I followed everything you said to do, and I am still not having any luck. I sort of had an application that created the frame first, but it did it different from your so I tried yours. Here is what I originally had for the application: http://pastebin.com/NinUypkH and here is what I have now: http://pastebin.com/6dJ7zNkw

Comment: I see, you just wanted to run your app logic in the GUI thread while the GUI didn't finish his work yet. You might want to run it in another working thread. Try this `    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {//do your logic here
                               
         }
      });
`